# ZeroMQ can subscribe, but how to exclude a specific filter?

Tags: zeromq, publish-subscribe, distributed-system

In ZeroMQ we can subscribe to a topic, with some filter

`socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "/someRoot/")`

Is there a way to exclude a specific filter from being sent?

For example, how can we exclude `"/someRoot/noise/"` from being sent?

Sure, we can check for it on a subscriber side, but I would like to avoid it from being even sent to this subscriber in the first place...

Is this possible with ZeroMQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your point of view correctly, yes, that is pretty possible using ZeroMQ tools, just:

### create a **`CensorProxy`** ( a Man-In-The-Middle pattern )

and assemble a client-**`XSUB/XPUB`**-`[MITM-PolicyMaker]`-**`SUB/PUB`** pipeline, where MITM-Censor will implement the policies, what is allowed to subscribe to and what is not.

Hope this helps more the good boys side than the bad boys side.

Comment: yes but that will mean that no one else can subscribe to "/someRoot/noise" which is not what we need, we want spcific subscriber (which is aware that it does not want this data) not to receive it, but some other subscriber actually needs it and it will not want to filter it out...

Comment: or more simply, haveing a publisher what we want is SubscriberA (that wants everything) SubscriberB (that wants everything except some specific thing)

Comment: **Both are possible**. Just integrate a "negative"-subscribe pattern matching into the **`[MITM-PolicyMaker]`** code, where the inital positive-subscribes will locally arrive and where all the intended "negative"-subscribe(s) matching will happen, so that the final down-stream ( to the "screened" client ) will not contain any of the "negative"-subscribed cases. ( Possibilities are pretty wild here, aren't they? )